# Morphological closing for skewed lines

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have some skewed lines that I want to perform morphological closing ever, I am not sure how I should define the closing kernel in this case. The problem is that the lines may sometimes be skewed and sometimes be perfectly vertical. In this case, how would I define the kernel?

For reference, the image I am working on looks like this - I want to join the lines on the right-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines are quite neat, but they are thin, so the required closing should be very accurate. For this you need to measure the skew angle. (Then you can deskew and apply a purely vertical structuring element.)

I'd rather work this out differently than with morphology, which is a blind, global operation that will damage your image.

- Detect the line segments (you may think of Hough, but line tracing and Douglas-Peucker vectorization seems better).
- Optionally, line fitting on the segments, for maximum accuracy.
- Finally, join the segment that have nearby endpoints and similar direction.

Comment: I am currently using an LSD Detector for the line segments, the image above ^ is the output of lsd. So I have the endpoints of each line segment. Could you tell me more about the line fitting procedure?

Comment: @PyWalker2797: you should have said it upfront ! Just use the LSD data as is. You might even group the segments in facing pairs for better robustness. Please forget any low-level processing.

Comment: What do you mean by facing pairs? My initial approach was to close the gap by identifying line segments which are very close to each other, for example (x1, y1, x2, y2) is one line segment, i check if the `y2` is close to the next line segments `y1` this will verify if they are aligned, but it seems like this is O(n^2) because i have to iterate over all the line segments twice.

Comment: Brute force is O(N²). You can improve to O(N Log N) by means of computational geometry techniques. But is it worth the effort when N=12 ?

Comment: What approach would work best, should I calculate the angles between two lines? For each line I calculate its angle with over other line, if the angle is same I join them else I move on to the next?

Comment: @PyWalker2797: join the segment that have nearby endpoints and similar direction.